# Attoparsec - ensure entire contents consumed with sepBy1

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I would like the below code to return `[LoadInt 1,LoadDub 2.5,LoadInt 3]`, but it fails after parsing `[LoadInt 1,LoadDub 2]` and facing `.5,3`. How do I make it so it must parse all the way to the comma for a parse to succeed, and an `int` parse on `2.5` is a fail?

```
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 as A
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 (Parser)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack)
import Data.Attoparsec.Combinator
import Control.Applicative ((*>),(<$>),(<|>))
data LoadNum = LoadInt Int | LoadDub Double deriving (Show)

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = putStrLn . show $ A.parseOnly (lnParser <* A.endOfInput) (pack testString)


testString :: String
testString = "1,2.5,3"

lnParser :: Parser [LoadNum]
lnParser = (sepBy1' (ld <* A.atEnd) (A.char ','))

double :: Parser Double
double = A.double

int :: Parser Int
int = A.signed A.decimal

ld :: Parser LoadNum
ld = ((LoadInt <$> int ) <|> (LoadDub <$> double))
```

Comment: Is the best thing to do a 2 part parse here, first to a comma separated list, then on each element? Isn't that slow?

Comment: I have this horrible solution but it makes me feel bad because it is bad `join $ sequence <$> (fmap . fmap) (A.parseOnly ld . pack)  (A.parseOnly parseCommaList (pack "1,2,34.2"))`

Comment: where `parseCommaList = sepBy1' (A.many1 (A.notChar ',')) (A.char ',')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a tiny bit of lookahead to decide whether you reached the end of a list element. So:

```
int :: Parser Int
int = do
    i <- A.signed A.decimal
    next <- A.peekChar
    case next of
        Nothing -> pure i
        Just ',' -> pure i
        _ -> fail "nah"
```